# Linguagem e Ambiente do AWS

Tags: amazon-aws

Conhecendo o [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/) eu fiquei curioso para saber em qual (ou quais) linguagem ele é implementado e em que servidor(es) web ele é executado.

Pesquisando, o máximo que encontrei a página da própria amazon [sobre a infra-estrutura global](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/about-aws/global-infrastructure/).

Apenas por curiosidade, caso em alguém saiba. Que linguagem usam? Quais servidores de aplicação. etc.

Comment: Praticamente todas possíveis. Aquilo é uma monstruosidade para ser feia em apenas uma linguagem.

Comment: Onde seria o local mais adequado para eu fazer a pergunta novamente?!

Comment: Provavelmente em lugar algum, como eu já demonstrei a informação é difícil de responder, não faz sentido e a resposta seria irrelevante, mas tenta perguntar para a AWS, provavelmente nem eles sabem de forma centralizada.